Proof of why $ d|X| = |X|\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX) $?
I am trying to understand why the identity
$$ d|X| = |X|\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX) $$
How can we mathematically prove this?
I am not sure how to do this, so I tried to verify this for a small example:
$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} 
x & y \\
z & w
\end{bmatrix} $$
Step 1: Calculate $|X|$
$$ |X| = xw - yz $$
Step 2: Calculate $d|X|$
$$ d|X| = \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial w}dw $$
Calculate each partial derivative:
$$ \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial x} = w $$
$$ \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial y} = -z $$
$$ \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial z} = -y $$
$$ \frac{\partial |X|}{\partial w} = x $$
Substituting these back into theequation:
$$ d|X| = w\,dx - z\,dy - y\,dz + x\,dw $$
Step 3: Now, to verify $d|X| = |X|\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX)$:
Calculate $X^{-1}$
$$ X^{-1} = \frac{1}{xw-yz} \begin{bmatrix}
w & -y \\
-z & x
\end{bmatrix} $$
Step 4: Express $dX$
$$ dX = \begin{bmatrix}
dx & dy \\
dz & dw
\end{bmatrix} $$
Step 5: Calculate $X^{-1}dX$
$$ X^{-1}dX = \frac{1}{xw-yz} \begin{bmatrix}
w & -y \\
-z & x
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
dx & dy \\
dz & dw
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{xw-yz} \begin{bmatrix}
w\,dx - y\,dz & w\,dy - y\,dw \\
-z\,dx + x\,dz & -z\,dy + x\,dw
\end{bmatrix} $$
Step 6: Calculate $\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX)$
$$ \text{tr}(X^{-1}dX) = \frac{1}{xw-yz} (w\,dx - y\,dz - z\,dy + x\,dw) $$
Step 7: Calculate $|X|\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX)$
$$ |X|\text{tr}(X^{-1}dX) = (xw-yz) \cdot \frac{1}{xw-yz} (w\,dx - y\,dz - z\,dy + x\,dw) $$
$$ = w\,dx - y\,dz - z\,dy + x\,dw $$
After a lot of manipulation, I hope I have done this correctly. But can someone please help me prove this?

For a tedious derivation you could look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580268/27978

There are three derivations on the wiki page of Jacobi's formula : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula

HINT: By cofactor expansion, the coefficient of $dx_{ij}$ in $d|X|$ is the $ij$-cofactor of $X$. Now recall that $|X|X^{-1}$ is the transpose of the cofactor mateix.

thank you! I will look into it

(I have never heard of cofactor expansion..., I will need to read it)

Some people call it expansion by minors. It’s in every linear algebra book and certainly on Wiki.
